# Allow user to select which Measures are displayed in Power BI Matrix - SSAS Live connection

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop

I have created a simple report  using  Power BI Desktop connecting to our SSAS cube using **Live Connection**.

The report contains a couple of slicers and a Matrix. In the matrix, I have list of team members on "Rows" and for the "Values" (cannot added measures in columns), I have selected a number of different measures from our SSAS cube.

I have been asked to include a selector/slicer which will allow for user to toggle/select which measures are displayed in the matrix visual.

It seems I am unable to add a measure to a slicer, and unsure how to accomplish this. I've been googling around and searching for some solutions, but most of the solutions are for Imported datasets and/or SSAS Tabular data models, whereas here, I am using Live Connection to Multidimensional cube.

I have seen some similar questions from others using SSAS Live Connection to Multidimensional model, but the answers provided always seem to be something along the lines of:

"Must be done in the cube.." or "You have to handle that in the model at the source"

But I'm unsure as to *what* exactly I need to do in the cube... So, the question is:

**What change(s) do I need to make in our SSAS Multidimensional cube that will allow for Power BI report user to toggle which measures are displayed in Power BI Matrix visual?**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new table in your model for this scenario. Something along the lines of:

| Slicer | Column | Slicer sort | Column sort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Option A | A1 | 1 | 1 |
| Option A | A2 | 1 | 2 |
| Option A | A3 | 1 | 3 |
| Option B | B1 | 2 | 1 |
| Option B | B2 | 2 | 2 |

You can of course chose your own names for the column names.
`Slicer` is what will be used for the slicer.
`Column` is what will be used in visuals.
`Slicer sort` to help with sort ordering of the `Slicer`.
`Column sort` to help with sort ordering of the `Column`.

Then you'll need to create a new Measure that is similar to:

```
My new dynamic measure = 
  SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('NewTableAbove'[Column],
    "A1", [A1 Measure],
    "A2", [A2 Measure],
    "A3", [A3 Measure],
    
    "B1", [B1 Measure],
    "B2", [B2 Measure]
  )
```

And that should get you want you need.

Comment: Where/How am I supposed to create this table? This is a multidimensional cube. Not tabular model.

Comment: Doh! My bad. Will post an alternative answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that can be achieved report-side without needing to modify your multi-dimensional cube.

**Overview**

- Have two (or more) instances of your Matrix on the page, each with the different set of desired measures.
- Use Power BI Bookmarks, one for each, that shows and hides the respective Matrixes/Matrices.
- Use the relatively new Bookmark navigator to allow the user to switch between the two (or more). Note - the Bookmark navigator will look like a set of buttons and not like a typical slicer.

**Bookmark Steps**

1. Duplicate your matrix, and change the measures as desired.
2. Position your new matrix directly over the original.
3. Open the Selection pane and Bookmarks pane (Under `View` tab in the ribbon).
4. In the Selection pane, hide one of your Matrixes by clicking on the eye icon.
5. In the Selection pane, select both Matrixes, then in the Bookmarks pane, click `Add`.
6. Next to your new Bookmark (`Bookmark 1`) click on the `...` on the right, and select `Display` and `Selected visuals`, and unselect the rest. You should have it like so:
   [image]
7. Again, `...` on the bookmark and select `Update` - ensure that both visuals are selected in the Selection pane.
8. Now in the Selection pane, show/hide the Matrixes the other-way round
9. Repeat steps 5 to 7 for the second bookmark.
10. Finally, rename each bookmark as you'd like to them show on the report for the user to select between.

**Adding Bookmark navigator**

1. In the `Insert` tab in the ribbon, Select `Buttons` > `Navigator` > `Bookmark navigator`
2. Customize the properties, look'n'feel as desired

**Tip** - if you are going to have a few of these in a report, then do Group your bookmarks, then in the Bookmark navigator properties, you can specify a bookmark group (Visual > Bookmarks).

Comment: Nope. That won’t work either :( I saw a blog post with similar suggestion and explored, but I have too many measures and user wants to be able to select multiple selections. Would be too many visuals and wouldn’t give the functionality they’re wanting. Plus, trying to teach users to do something new with extra steps than what their used to never goes over well…

Comment: It's either this answer or the previous answer. Maybe somebody else has alternative solutions. It does sound like the other answer is what you need - is it possible to add a new dimension to your cube without any facts?

Comment: I may have to explore that further. If that’s what I have to do, though, it’s not really ideal… having to create how many x number of one off dimensions to handle this scenario for how many x number of  reporting cases/needs seems crazy to me.

Comment: It is crazy, I thought your question was for a handful of set measures. A report is designed and built, and hopeful meet the needs for a majority of users. For those who need more then suggest a Self-Serve approach, let folks connect to the cube and build their own reports, whether in PBI or Excel. One other idea to explore is using "Perspectives" together with Personalize Visuals, see [Let users personalize visuals in a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-personalize-visuals?tabs=powerbi-desktop)